# react is missing from redux-devtools

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am relatively new to react and webpack, and I just picked up a new project to work on. To configure DevTool, we have:

```
export function renderDevTools(store) {
    if (__DEV__) {
        let {DevTools, DebugPanel, LogMonitor} = require('redux-devtools/lib/react');
        return (
            <DebugPanel top right bottom>
            <DevTools store={store} monitor={LogMonitor} />
            </DebugPanel>
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

From the node_module, I can see:

```
\node_modules\redux-devtools\lib\
```

has

```
createDevTools.js
index.js
persistState.js
```

but there is no react.js in this folder, so running the code will give:

```
ERROR in ./app/utils/devTools.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'redux-devtools/lib/react'
```

I have tried

```
npm install redux-devtools
```

but there is still missing react from the file. This is a legacy code, and when I tried running it, it isn't working. I am wondering what went wrong?

Comment: This legacy code probably uses an older version of redux-devtools. For the most current version, you can find a walkthrough here: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough.md

Comment: This video explains how to connect redux devtool to basic react redux app - https://youtu.be/TSOVLXQPWgA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is for `redux-devtools@2`. In `redux-devtools@3` monitors are decoupled into `redux-devtools-log-monitor` and `redux-devtools-dock-monitor`, which you have also to install and add to you project as indicated in [the docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough.md).

Also you have to set `__DEV__` as `true` in `webpack.config` (which should be different for development and production):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    '__DEV__': true
  })
],
```

A easier way is not to include it directly into your app, but to use [Chrome / Firefox extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension). Then you can add it to your Redux store [with just one line of code](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#11-basic-store):

```
const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
```

Make sure to remove everything else related to Redux DevTools in this case.

If you're using the extension you can use it also in production [without any edge cases](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/185), otherwise make sure to remove it from production bundle.

Comment: Do you know where `DebugPanel` goes? I'm maintaining a huge code written by others, and the change makes me super helpless due to I don't know how to fix the codes :(